# Prove a residue matrix $A$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_n)$ has an inverse if and only if $\gcd(\det A,n) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, cryptography

> Prove a residue matrix $A$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_n)$ has an inverse if and only if $\gcd(\det A,n) = 1$.

I've always done matrix arithmetic in a field $\mathbb F$ and that is what every Linear Algebra book has taught me to do.

However, I've started looking into Cryptography and here the term **residue matrix** come up.

Can someone prove the above result or tell me where to look it up ?

Where can I find books about **Cryptography-related Linear Algebra** ? I've studied several books on Linear Algebra, but they are all equal in the sense that the ring of interest is a field.

Normally a matrix $A$ (with coefficients in a field $\mathbb F$) has an inverse if and only if $\det A \neq 0$, and in this case $\det A$ is neccesarily invertible, since we are in a field. So the above result is a more general result than this.

Comment: Hint: the inverse of $A$ has a nice expression as the transposed of the comatrix (or [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)) divided by the determinant.

Comment: $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$.

Comment: Is it straight forward to see that all the results proved about $\det A$ in a field $\mathbb F$ are also valid for an arbitrary commutative ring $R$ ? ($\det(AB) = \det(A) \det (B)$ etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is. Look at a proof of that identity, and see whether you use anything not true in commutative rings generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over a commutative ring $R$ a matrix $A$ is invertible iff $\det A$ is a unit: see [Invertible matrices over a commutative ring and their determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221681/invertible-matrices-over-a-commutative-ring-and-their-determinants). In your case this means exactly $\gcd(\det A,n)=1$.

Comment: So the proof is that simple, just by considering the adjoint matrix $\text {adj} A$ and seeing that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ implies $\det A$ is a unit, which in $\mathbb Z_n$ is true if and only if $\gcd (\det A, n) = 1$. I thought the results $\det(AB) = \det (A) \det (B)$ and so on were true only for a field !

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen There are a lot of nice proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60284/how-to-show-that-detab-deta-detb).