# Counting number of unique $k$-dimensional subspaces over ring of integers mod $p^m$, generated by $VD$, where $D$ is a defined diagonal matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, hermite-normal-form

I would like to count the number of unique $k$-dimensional subspaces of the form $VD$, where $V\in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z/({p^m}))$ is some $n\times n$ matrix defined over the ring of integers modulo $p^m$, for some prime $p$ and integer $m$, i.e., $\mathbb Z/(p^m)$. Furthermore, $D$ is some predefined diagonal matrix with elements $d_i\in\{p^0,p^1,
\dots,p^m\}$.

In other words, given $D=\text{diag}(\mathbf d)$, defining the set

$$S_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)=\{VD : V\in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z/(p^m)),D=\text{diag}(\mathbf d) \},$$

what is the number of elements $S_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)$ that are unique up to linear transformations on the right-hand side?

Defining
$$\begin{aligned}T_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)=S_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)/GL(n,\mathbb Z/({p^m}))&=\{S_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)R:R \in GL(n,\mathbb Z/(p^m))\}\\
&=\{\{XR:X\in S_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)\}:R \in GL(n,\mathbb Z/(p^m))\},\end{aligned}$$
the question is to find the cardinality of $T_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)$, i.e., $|T_{n,p^m}(\mathbf d)|$. The answer will be some function depending on $\mathbf d$, $n$ and $p^m$.

**General Examples**

- if $d_i=1$ for all $i$, then we have the trivial case of a single $n$-dimensional subspace.
- if $d_i=1$ for all $i\le k$ with $d_i=0$ otherwise, then we can count the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces on $\mathbb Z_{p^m}$ according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142590/510788).

For other choices of $D$ the problem becomes complicated.

**Solution attempts**

I originally tried to solve the problem by considering $V$ as defined in terms of $m$ matrices over the field $\mathbb Z_p$ but I am not sure this method avoids overcounting.

Alternatively, consider the column Hermite normal form of $VD$, which is a unique triangular matrix $H_{VD}=VDU$, with $U$ a unimodular matrix. If there exists some $R$ such that $VDR=V'D$ then the Hermite normal form of $VD$ and $V'D$ will be the same. Hence, we can count the number of Hermite normal form that exist.

The question then becomes, how many unique matrices $H$ exist, where each $H$ is a Hermite normal form of a matrix of the form $VD$?

**Specific example**

As a simple example of what I mean, consider $n=2$ with $p^m=2^4$. If I define $\mathbf d=(0,1)^T$, I want to count all the unique subspaces of the form $VD$ where $V=(\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2)$, where we see that $VD=(0,\mathbf v_2)$. Hence, in this case, the size of $T_{2,2^4}(\mathbf d)$, with $\mathbf d=(0,1)^T$ is equivalent to the number of subpaces of $GL(2,\mathbb Z/(16))$ consisting of only one vector $\mathbf v_2$. The question becomes, how many choices of $\mathbf v_2$ exist such that the set $\{(0,\mathbf v_2) R : R\in GL(n,\mathbb Z/({p^m}))\}$ is unique? In this case, this is equivalent to the question of the number of unique sets of the form $\{R^T\mathbf v_2 : GL(n,\mathbb Z/(p^m))\}$, which is in turn equivalent to asking the number of unique $1$-dimensional subspaces of the $n$-dimensional space $GL(n,\mathbb Z/({p^m}))$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$ is not a field, its characteristic is not prime, so how does the linked answer apply? I guess this is not important to the main question, but what do you mean by subspaces? For a specific diagonal matrix $D$, you have the left $GL$-orbit, and you want to know the number of suborbits it splits into under the right $GL$-action — did I get you right?

Comment: This is not 'linear-algebra' BTW, might be more suitable for 'ring-theory'.

Comment: There's no such isomorphism, these groups have different cardinality. You can talk of a $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$-submodule instead of a subspace. The orbits I meant are of the left and right group actions of $GL$ on the whole ring of matrices over $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the suborbits of $S_{n,p^m}({\bf d})$ under the right $GL$-action have equal sizes, since they are transitively permuted by the left $GL$-action, which conserves the sizes. (Since the orbits $O_U = UD \cdot GL$ and $O_V = VD \cdot GL$ are related by $O_U = U V^{-1} O_V$, we have $|O_U| \le |O_V|$).

The order of the group that acts is $|GL_n(\Bbb Z_{p^m})| = p^{(m-1) n^2} |GL_n(\Bbb Z_{p})| = p^{(m-1) n^2} \prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (p^n - p^i)$, since a matrix over $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$ is invertible whenever its projection to $\Bbb Z_p$ is invertible (you can deduce this from the determinant invertibility criterion, or just construct the inverse explicitly in some other way than using the adjugate).

Let $D = I_{k_0} \oplus p I_{k_1} \oplus \ldots \oplus p^{m-1} I_{k_{m-1}} \oplus 0 I_{k_m}$ (matrix direct sum, $\sum k_i = n$).

Denote $R = \Bbb Z_{p^m}$.

(1) Over a commutative ring, a matrix is invertible [whenever](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221681/invertible-matrices-over-a-commutative-ring-and-their-determinants) its determinant is invertible. The noninvertible elements of $R$ are exactly $p R$, so the determinant must project to a nonzero element of $\Bbb Z_p$.

(2) Define sets $S_U = U \cdot D \cdot GL$ for $U \in GL_n(R)$. Then left multiplication by another element $A$ of $GL$ permutes these sets: $A S_U = S_{AU}$, and we have $GL$ *transitively* left-acting on the set $\Sigma$ of these sets $S_U$. You asked for $T = |\Sigma|$, the length of the orbit, which is the index of the stabilizer of an *arbitrary* element of the orbit by the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242968/intuition-on-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem). So we can take $U$ the identity matrix and compute the left stabilizer of $D \cdot GL$.

Let's find the matrices $V$ such that $V \cdot D \cdot GL \subset D \cdot GL$. This is equivalent to existence of an invertible $K$ such that $V D = DK$.

Right multiplication by $D$ scales the columns, left multiplication scales rows. Divide our matrices into blocks so that the diagonal ones are square of sizes respectively $k_0, \ldots, k_m$.

The condition **(on $Q$)** "$\exists V, K$: $VD = DK = Q$" is equivalent for $Q$ to belong to the following set of block diagonal matrices, where **by $p^k R$ I mean *any* submatrix with entries from that ideal** (and the **enumeration of block indices starts from $0$**). Note that we don't *yet* assume $V, K$ to be invertible:

$$Q \in \begin{pmatrix}
R & pR & p^2 R & \cdots & p^{m-1}R & 0\\
pR & pR & p^2 R & \cdots & p^{m-1}R & 0\\
p^2 R & p^2 R & p^2 R & \ldots & p^{m-1}R & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
p^{m-1}R & p^{m-1}R & p^{m-1}R & \cdots & p^{m-1}R & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

so, "dividing by the powers $p^k$", we can now treat the condition **on $V$** "$\exists K$: $VD = DK$" **($V, K$ not necessarily invertible)**.

First note that in the leftmost (0-th) block column of $V$, which is scaled by $1$ when right-multiplied by $D$, the diagonal block $V_{10}$ cannot contain invertible elements (i.e. its entries are in $p R$) — otherwise $VD$ would also have an invertible element in the same block, and this would contradict the above analysis of possible $Q$'s.  In the same way, the block $V_{20}$ has to consist only of elements that belong to $p^2 R$, and so on until we get that $V_{m0}$ should be zero.

The same procedure applies for the blocks **that are below the diagonal** in the next column: $D$ multiplies the block column by $p = p^1$, so $V_{21}$ has to consist of elements in $pR$ (for them to end up in $p^2 R$ in $VD$), and so on until $V_{m1}$ which is to be comprised of elements of $p^{m-1} R$. Carry out the same procedure for all block columns. **Note** that the elements of the diagonal or above-diagonal blocks of $V$ do not suffer from the conditions on $Q$, as they are being multiplied by a high power of $p$, so in $V$ we can put anything there. So the set of *not necessarily invertible* $V$'s is the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
R & R & R & \cdots & R & R\\
pR & R & R & \cdots & R & R\\
p^2 R & p R & R & \ldots & R & R\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
p^{m-1}R & p^{m-2}R & p^{m-3}R & \cdots & R & R \\
0 & p^{m-1}R & p^{m-2}R & \cdots & pR & R
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is also straightforward to see the existence of $K$ for all matrices $V$ we found (again, both are not yet assumed to be invertible).

Now we have to ensure the condition $V \in GL$. The projection of any $V$ to $\Bbb Z_p$ is a block upper-triangular matrix; such matrices are invertible whenever each of their diagonal blocks is. Then the set of *invertible* $V$'s is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
GL & R & R & \cdots & R & R\\
pR & GL & R & \cdots & R & R\\
p^2 R & p R & GL & \ldots & R & R\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
p^{m-1}R & p^{m-2}R & p^{m-3}R & \cdots & GL & R \\
0 & p^{m-1}R & p^{m-2}R & \cdots & pR & GL
\end{pmatrix}$$

And, of course, for such an invertible $V$ there always exists an **invertible** $K$, if we take the first block row the same as in $VD$; in the second block row, the same as $VD$, but "divided" (arbitrarily) by $p$; and so on.

The total number of invertible $V$'s is thus

$$h = |R|^\alpha \times \prod\limits_{i = 0}^{m} |GL_{k_i}(R)| \times \prod\limits_{\ell = 1}^{m-1} p^{(m - \ell) \beta_\ell},$$

- where the first part concerns the entries on the block diagonal and above it, $\alpha = \sum\limits_{s = 0}^m \left(k_s \sum\limits_{t = s}^m k_t\right )$;
- the second is the block diagonal entries;
- the third is below the block diagonal, $\beta_\ell = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m-\ell} k_i k_{i + \ell}$ is the total number of entries in a "subdiagonal" that corresponds to $p^\ell R$.

This is the order of the stabilizer, so $T_{n,p^m} = |GL_n(R)|/h$. As I wrote before, $|GL_a(R)| = p^{(m - 1)a^2} |GL_a(\Bbb Z_p)|$, so you can use this to expand the formulae.

Comment: Why is a matrix over $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ invertible when projected onto $\mathbb Z_k$? And by projection, do you mean taking $M \mod p$ or  $M p^(k-1)$?

Comment: Could you please also make the beginning explanation more explicit? I am confused as to why you can count $D\cdot GL$ only. I understand that the size of $|U \cdot D GL|=|D\cdot GL|$ but why does this mean it is enough to count $D \cdot GL$ ?

Comment: I am concerned that maybe this is not correct. You seem to assume that $U$ is some constant (but unknown) matrix, like $D$. I.e., you seem to count the number of unique elements of $O_U=\{UDV : V \in GL\}$ for any $U$, i.e., $|O_U|$. However, what I want is the number of unique suborbits for all $U$. I.e., my question is to identify the number of sets $O_U$ that are unique, over all $U$. I.e., given $U$ and $V$, if the two sets $O_U=O_V$, only count $O_U$. Formally, $|\{O_U : U \in GL\}|=|\{\{UDV : V \in GL\} :U \in GL\}|$. Perhaps this is equivalent to your answer, but I do not see how.

Comment: Yes, I've realized 13h ago that my argument here is incorrect (I came up with the first paragraph after I've done all the calculations, but did not bother to recheck the logic another time despite feeling something missing). Everything after "The stabilizer of $D$" is unrelated to your question. I'm currently writing up another solution.

Comment: @Cameron Added a section after "Edit".