# matrix with univariate entries: rank deficit of specialization ≤ vanishing order of determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, matrix-rank

fix a field $F$ and consider an $n \times n$ matrix $M(X)$ with entries in $F[X]$. the determinant $\det(M(X))$ is itself a polynomial, say $D(X)$.

clearly, if $x \in F$ is such that the specialized $\text{rank}(M(x)) < n$, then $D(x) = 0$. i want to say more:

**Claim.** If $x \in F$ is such that $\text{rank}(M(x)) \leq n - d$, then $D(x)$ vanishes to order $\geq d$; that is, $(X - x)^d \mid D(X)$ in $F[X]$.

Comment: i think this will be _harder_ to prove in characteristic 2 (which is actually what i care about), but I don't even have a proof in any characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix over a commutative ring is invertible [whenever](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221681) its determinant is, so multiplying $M$ by invertible matrices would change neither quantity. $F[X]$ is a PID, so we have the Smith normal form, and for diagonal matrices the claim is rather evident: at least $d$ diagonal entries are zero in the specialization, and $X-x$ divides each of these.

Comment: thank you; this settles the original question. i hate to move the goalposts; but any leads for the same problem, but for $F$ replaced by a reduced commutative ring with unit (but necessarily an integral domain)? thanks in advance.

Comment: @BD107 Do you mean "not necessarily an integral domain"? What [kind](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29993/rank-of-a-module) of rank do you want to use?

Comment: yes, and good question—let me break this out into a new question.

Comment: done https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4875490/308170